# Process#spawn results in "No such file or directory - open (Errno::ENOENT)"

Tags: ruby, process, io-redirection

Is it just me or is there a bug in Ruby's `Process#spawn` when redirecting output to a file?  [The documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Process.html#method-c-spawn) says:

```
redirection:
  key:
    FD              : single file descriptor in child process
    [FD, FD, ...]   : multiple file descriptor in child process
  value:
    FD                        : redirect to the file descriptor in parent process
    string                    : redirect to file with open(string, "r" or "w")
    [string]                  : redirect to file with open(string, File::RDONLY)
    [string, open_mode]       : redirect to file with open(string, open_mode, 0644)
    [string, open_mode, perm] : redirect to file with open(string, open_mode, perm)
    [:child, FD]              : redirect to the redirected file descriptor
    :close                    : close the file descriptor in child process
  FD is one of follows
    :in     : the file descriptor 0 which is the standard input
    :out    : the file descriptor 1 which is the standard output
    :err    : the file descriptor 2 which is the standard error
```

So I should be able to have the key as `[:out, :err]` and the value as a string representing a filename, but:

```
% ruby -e 'spawn("ps -ef", [:out, :err] => "foo")'
-e:1:in `spawn': No such file or directory - open (Errno::ENOENT)
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

(BTW I've tested with 2.1.2 and 2.0.0, and there doesn't seem to be any difference.)

If I first create the file, the behaviour changes:

```
% touch foo
% ruby -e 'spawn("ps -ef", [:out, :err] => "foo")'
```

However nothing is written to the file, and removing `:err` from the redirection key proves that something went wrong when setting up the redirection:

```
% cat foo
% ruby -e 'spawn("ps -ef", [:out] => "foo")' 2>err
% cat err
ps: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

It's fairly easy to work around this weirdness and get the behaviour I want, e.g.

```
% rm -f foo
% ruby -e 'Process.waitpid(spawn("ps -ef", [:out, :err] => ["foo", "w"]))'
% wc foo
  503  4422 36470 foo
```

or

```
% rm -f foo
% ruby -e 'Process.waitpid(spawn("ps -ef", :out => "foo", :err => :out))'
% wc foo
  503  4422 36470 foo
```

but since I've wasted 30 minutes due to the documentation apparently not matching the actual behaviour, I'd love to know if it's a genuine bug or just my misunderstanding.

My suspicion is that when using the form which groups multiple `FD`s within a single `Array`, Ruby stops attempting to auto-detect whether it should open the `FD`s in read or write mode, and just opens in read mode.  Then this fails when the process tries to write to it.  This seems to be confirmed by the lack of any error or even warning from Ruby when you attempt to mix input/output `FD`s within the same `Array`:

```
% yes | head -n3 > foo
% ruby -e 'Process.waitpid(spawn("wc", [:in, :out] => "foo"))'
wc: write error
% cat foo
y
y
y
% yes | head -n3 > foo
% ruby -e 'Process.waitpid(spawn("wc", [:in, :out] => ["foo"]))'
wc: write error
% cat foo
y
y
y
```

But I'm sure other people can offer better explanations.

Comment: Yes, by the [sources](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/process.c#2913) it *autodetects* open mode only for one source descriptor. I don't think the documentation is wrong, it only may add warning to explicitly specify mode when multiple descriptors are to be redirected. What do you expect in ambiguous situation, when read-only and write-only descriptors are specified ? `[:in, :out] => 'some_file.txt'`

Comment: I would expect an exception, or at least a warning.  I'm pretty convinced the documentation is wrong (in the sense of being incomplete) because it doesn't properly explain how or when the open mode auto-detection works.

Comment: The source link in the above comment is broken - see instead [`process.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/process.c) (e.g. search for `"err"`).